# advanced custome fields and custom post type ui wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

i have a problem
please someone tell me where is the problem in this code

```
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'about_us', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' )); ?>
    <?php while($loop -> have_post()) : $loop -> the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <i class="<?php the_field('about_us_icon'); ?>" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div class="textA">
                <h3><?php the_field('about_us_title'); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_field('about_us_text'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

and thank you !!

Comment: what is the issue you are facing actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
<h3><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'about_us_title',true); ?></h3>
<p><?php echo  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'about_us_text',true); ?></p>
```

Assuming here that you are having the meta key in the postmeta for the each post

Comment: Check meta table does this values are in the postmeta table?

Answer (score 0):

thank u all
i found the problem
it's in the post per page

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'about_us', 'posts_per_page' => 6 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

i forget to add the posts_per_page
thank u all for ur time